# Scrollable Terms and Conditions in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to develop a scrollable terms and conditions in visualforce page.Content in Terms and Conditions is **dynamic** (Some of the content is from Account,Opportunity and Opportunity Line Item).Content in it has around **10 pages** in length.What is the approach that I need to follow to build something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

```
<div style="height:400px; overflow-y:scroll">
   lots of text
   lots of text
    lots of text
</div>
```

?

Or possibly

```
<div style="height:400px; overflow-y:auto">
   lots of text
   lots of text
    lots of text
</div>
```